# My Animation is not working in React using UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend

```
import plus from "../../assets/plus.png";

import styled, { css, keyframes } from "styled-components";
import Data from "../../database/favouriteData";
import Filter from "../Filter";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Main = styled.div`
  background-color: rgb(250, 247, 247);
  height: 800px;
`;
const Menu = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  gap: 300px;
`;
const FilterButton = styled.div`
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
`;
const Plus = styled.img`
  width: 20px;
`;
const ListElement = styled.li`
  color: #363636;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
  ${(props) => (props.active ? `color:red;font-weight: 800;` : ``)};
`;
const MenContent = styled.div`
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
`;
const Item = styled.div`
  padding-bottom: 20px;
`;
const ShoeBackground = styled.div`
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation: ${(props) =>
    props.isAnimated
      ? css`
          ${fadeIn} 0.5s ease-in-out
        `
      : ``};
`;
const Shoe = styled.img`
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
`;
const ShoeTitle = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 1px;
  text-align: left;
`;
// keyframes
const fadeIn = keyframes`
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
`;
function TheStore() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState({
    men: true,
    women: false,
    kids: false,
  });
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState(() => {
    const filteredData = Data.filter((shoe) => shoe.for === "men"); // Replace 'men' with the desired value
    return filteredData;
  });
  const [close, setClose] = useState(false);
  const [isAnimated, setIsAnimated] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsAnimated(true);
    // clean  up the animation when the componennt is unmount
    return () => {
      setIsAnimated(false);
    };
  }, []);
  function handleActive(item) {
    setGenre(() => {
      const filteredData = Data.filter((shoe) => shoe.for === item);
      return filteredData;
    });

    setActive((props) => {
      const updateState = { ...props, [item]: !props[item] };

      for (let element in updateState) {
        if (element !== item) {
          updateState[element] = false;
        }
      }
      return updateState;
    });
  }
  function handleOpenCloseFilter() {
    setClose(!close);
  }
  return (
    <Main>
      <Menu>
        <ListElement>
          <FilterButton onClick={handleOpenCloseFilter}>
            <p>Filter</p>
            <Plus alt="plus" src={plus} />
          </FilterButton>
          {close ? <Filter /> : ""}
        </ListElement>

        <ListElement active={active.men} onClick={() => handleActive("men")}>
          Men
        </ListElement>
        <ListElement
          active={active.women}
          onClick={() => handleActive("women")}
        >
          Women
        </ListElement>
        <ListElement active={active.kids} onClick={() => handleActive("kids")}>
          Kids
        </ListElement>
      </Menu>

      <MenContent className="store">
        {genre.map((shoe) => (
          <Item>
            <ShoeBackground isAnimated={isAnimated}>
              <Shoe alt={shoe.shoeName} src={shoe.picture} />
            </ShoeBackground>
            <ShoeTitle>
              <h4>{shoe.shoeName}</h4>
              <p> {shoe.price}</p>
            </ShoeTitle>
          </Item>
        ))}
      </MenContent>
    </Main>
  );
}
export default TheStore;
```

as you can see up is my code, what I would like to render is that whenever I click on Men or Woman the animation is triggered, but this is not working, i tried to change the state of isAnimated in isActive it worked but only once and not all the time.
my code is sometimes working only on few elements and this only when I come from Kids to woman or from kid to men